# update object in list

Tags: java

> Q: I have a `Bank` class containing multiple loan accounts (`LoanAccount` class). I've create a `LoanAccountService` that have the CRUD functionalities. My concerns are about how I implemented the update functionality.

**Bank**

```
public class Bank {
    private List<LoanAccount> loanAccounts;
}
```

**Loan account**

```
public class LoanAccount {
    private String id;
    private Integer numberOfInstallments;
    private LoanAccountType type;
    private Date creationDate;
    private BigDecimal loanAmount;
}
```

**Service**

```
public class LoanAccountService{

    private Bank bank;

    public LoanAccountService(Bank bank) {
        this.bank = bank;
    }

    public LoanAccount update(LoanAccount loanAccount) {
        Optional<LoanAccount> account = bank.getLoanAccounts()
                .stream()
                .filter(la -> la.getId().equals(loanAccount.getId()))
                .findAny();
        if (account.isPresent()) {
            account.get().setCreationDate(loanAccount.getCreationDate());
            account.get().setLoanAmount(loanAccount.getLoanAmount());

        account.get().setNumberOfInstallments(loanAccount.getNumberOfInstallments());
            account.get().setType(loanAccount.getType());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The object does not exist.");
        }
        return loanAccount;
    }
}
```

When the method `update` is called with a `LoanAccount` containing an `id` that already exists in `loanAccounts` list, I want to update the existing object with the object `loanAccount` given as parameter.

Above is my implementation, but I feel like there should be better ways to do it.

Comment: Hello,  from your implementation it seems me that you can create a `loanaccount` instance with the same id of an existing one and after use the newer to update the older (you are also updating the creation date field). I expect instead to have all `loanaccounts` have at least different ids, is this the expected behaviour ?

Comment: _Why_ would you ever want to copy a `LoanAccount`? Please provide some context.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following:

1. Place operations to the objects that contain data for this operation. It will improve encapsulation and allow more flexible code reuse.
   Also it will be easy to test such implementation because of small methods.
2. Use more convenient structure. In this case `Map<String, LoanAccount>` (map id to loanAccount) instead of `List<LoanAccount>`

As you can see in this case service contains only required logic (how to react on loan absence). It is easy to read, test and understand.

**LoanAccountService.java**

```
public class LoanAccountService{

    private Bank bank;

    public LoanAccountService(Bank bank) {
        this.bank = bank;
    }

    public LoanAccount update(LoanAccount loanAccount) {
        if (!bank.updateLoanAccount(loanAccount)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The object does not exist.");
        }
        return loanAccount;
    }
}
```

**Bank.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Bank {
    private Map<String, LoanAccount> loanAccounts;

    public boolean updateLoanAccount(LoanAccount loanAccount) {
        LoanAccount loan = loanAccounts.get(loanAccount.getId());
        if (loan != null) {
            loan.update(loanAccount);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**LoanAccount.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class LoanAccount {
    private String id;
    private Integer numberOfInstallments;
    private LoanAccountType type;
    private Date creationDate;
    private BigDecimal loanAmount;

    public void update(LoanAccount loanAccount) {
        this.setCreationDate(loanAccount.getCreationDate());
        this.setLoanAmount(loanAccount.getLoanAmount());
        this.setNumberOfInstallments(loanAccount.getNumberOfInstallments());
        this.setType(loanAccount.getType());
    }
}
```

If you can't use this approach, you could made a small refactoring of the service (less code and "if conditions" are good things):

```
public LoanAccount update(LoanAccount loanAccount) {
    LoanAccount account = bank.getLoanAccounts()
            .stream()
            .filter(la -> la.getId().equals(loanAccount.getId()))
            .findAny()
            .orElseThrow(() ->  new IllegalArgumentException("The object does not exist."));
    account.setCreationDate(loanAccount.getCreationDate());
    account.setLoanAmount(loanAccount.getLoanAmount());
    account.setNumberOfInstallments(loanAccount.getNumberOfInstallments());
    account.setType(loanAccount.getType());
    return account;
}
```

Also I think you should return updated loan account.

Comment: In your last example it should be `acount.set...` not `account.get().set` (`account` is not a `Optional`).

Comment: Fixed. Thank you. Pasted not final version.

Answer (score 1):

## [Feature Envy](https://refactoring.guru/smells/feature-envy)

The `LoanAccountService` needs to know all fields from `LoanAccount` that gets updated:

> ```java
> account.get().setCreationDate(loanAccount.getCreationDate());
> account.get().setLoanAmount(loanAccount.getLoanAmount());
> account.get().setNumberOfInstallments(loanAccount.getNumberOfInstallments());
> account.get().setType(loanAccount.getType());
> ```

Now imagine `LoanAccount` would get a few more fields and they are updateable too but you forgot to change `LoanAccountService`.. This means `LoanAccountService` depends on `LoanAccount`..

A solution would be to add a new method to `LoanAccount`:

```java
public LoanAccount updateBy(LoanAccount other) {
  this.creationDate = other.creationDate();
  this.loanAmount = other.loanAmount();
  this.numberOfInstallments = other.numberOfInstallments();
  this.type = other.type();
  return this;
}
```

## [Optional#map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)

The if-statement

> `if (account.isPresent()) {`

can be replaced by the method `map` on Optional. With adding the new `updateBy` method:

```java
public LoanAccount updateBy(LoanAccount other) {
  bank.getLoanAccounts()
      .stream()
      .filter(la -> la.getId().equals(other.getId()))
      .findAny()
      .map(loanAccount -> loanAccount.updateBy(other))
      .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("The object does not exist."));
  return other;
}
```

## Further Improvement

A second [Feature Envy](https://refactoring.guru/smells/feature-envy) is in the following snipped:

> ```java
> bank.getLoanAccounts()
>    .stream()
>    .filter(la -> la.getId().equals(loanAccount.getId()))
> ```

Not the `LoanAccountService` should filter the data but the `Bank` itself should filter it:

```java
// in Bank.java

public Optinal<List<LoanAccount> findBy(int id) {
   return loanAccounts.stream()
                      .filter(la -> la.getId().equals(id))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

## All together

```java
// LoanAccountService.java

public LoanAccount updateBy(LoanAccount other) {
  bank.findBy(other.getId())
      .findAny()
      .map(loanAccount -> loanAccount.updateBy(other))
      .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("The object does not exist."));
  return other;
}
```

Comment: In `Bank::findBy` you have the wrong return type in the signature. Also `LoadAccountService::updateBy` is assuming `Bank::findBy` is returning a `Stream`. I'd also like to suggest to have `Bank::findBy` directly return a single (optional) `LoanAccount` by moving `.findAny()`  there instead of building an unneeded `List`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to focus on a different aspect:

I find it dangerous using the same class `LoanAccount` both as a storage class inside Bank and as a data transfer class in the API, because if by accident the code on the outside gets an storage instance then it could change it's data bypassing the service.

I'd suggest to make `LoanAccount` an interface containing only getters and use this in the API methods. Then `Bank` and the caller would have their own implementations that can't be modified by the other side.

Comment: Nice point!  Alternatively it is possible to introduce LoanAccountDTO and use it on Service API and outside (it has clear name). Also mapstruct can be used for transformation.